# image_view freeze after 3 seconds

Tags: ros, camera1394, ros-indigo, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to display a simple video stream using camera1394 and image_view on Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04. I start camera1394 with this command:

```
rosrun camera1394 camera1394_node _guid:=b09d01008f706od:=640x480_mono8 _iso_speed:=400 _frame_rate:=30
```

and then I start image_view with this:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=camera/image_raw
```

I can see the correct stream for about 3 seconds and then the image stream freeze, but I can still use 'q' to close the image_view, so image_view is not completely crashing. The problem is, there is no error message or anything so I don't know where the problem is. If I restart image_view, it display a new image and then stop immediately.

Does anyone ran into the same problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193876/image_view-freeze-after-3-seconds/) by [Alex1602](https://answers.ros.org/users/20351/alex1602/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-10-14**:
Similar: http://answers.ros.org/question/194741/image_proc-causes-images-to-hang/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem. It seems to be dependent on the amount of processor usage in the rest of the system. With several image_view windows open, half of them freeze in less than a second.

This problem appears to be present in 1.12.6 and greater. The major change was the move from using GTK to using OpenCV to display the image window. My temporary solution is to compile 1.12.5 from source.

Edit: Issue opened at https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/101
Edit: Fixed in 1.12.11

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-30**:
Have you opened a bug report for this yet?

**Comment by [Alex1602](https://answers.ros.org/users/20351/alex1602/) on 2014-10-01**:
That sound plausible. The same setup is working on my laptop with an i5 but not on the desktop with a core2 Duo. I'll try with 1.12.5 to see if it fixes the problem.

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-10-14**:
Is the issue with image_view only?  Without displaying the images, would code still have access to topics that are updating?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-14**:
Yes. This bug only applies to image_view. If you're having trouble with something else, you should ask a new question.